# How to create element randomly in screen position using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my HTML

```
<html><body style="
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 10000px;
">
<div id="DatA"><div class="img-magnifier-glass" style="
    bottom: -9999;
    left: 0;
"></div></div>

<floor style="
    border: 5px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500;
    height: 10px;
    left: 300;
    bottom: 100;
"></floor><style id="stylus-65" type="text/css" class="stylus">* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-magnifier-glass {
    line-height: 6.5;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

</style><floor style="
    border: 5px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000;
    height: 10px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10000;
"></floor></body></html>
```

I want to create element randomly in screen scroll position
I try this

```
createF = (a) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    xc = document.querySelector('floor').cloneNode();
    xc.style.top = Math.random() * Math.random() * 567 + "px";
    xc.style.left = (Math.random() * Math.random() * 600) + 300 + "px";
    xc.style.width = "50px";
    xc.style.height = "5px";
    document.querySelector("#DatA").append(xc);
  }
}
```

but it doesn't create element randomly in screen scroll position but it create element randomly in top of document even if i scroll to bottom. my html have 10000px height

I don't have any idea how to calculate and set position to where my screen scroll and then append randomly

Comment: `xc.style.top = Math.random() * Math.random() * 567 + "px"` `Math.random()` generates a number between 0 and 1. That means this formula will only ever generate a number between 0 and 567. Also, using it twice like this means the numbers are more likely to be towards 0.

Comment: that script is example, but what i want is to create it in where screen scroll not randomly in whole document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must take into account both the scroll position and the screen dimensions in order to generate items that are randomly positioned dependent on the screen scroll position.

```
createF = (a) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    const xc = document.querySelector('floor').cloneNode();
    const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const scrollX = window.scrollX;
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;
    
    // Generate random coordinates within the visible area
    const randomX = Math.random() * screenWidth + scrollX;
    const randomY = Math.random() * screenHeight + scrollY;
    
    xc.style.position = 'absolute';
    xc.style.top = randomY + 'px';
    xc.style.left = randomX + 'px';
    xc.style.width = '50px';
    xc.style.height = '5px';
    
    document.querySelector("#DatA").append(xc);
  }
}
```